# How to delete all but the latest .csv file in a ftp using php

Tags: php

I want to delete all but the latest .csv file in a few ftp directories. I want it to be a php script so I can set up a cron

I found and used the following script to delete all but not sure how to edit it to keep the latest file unless there is a better way of doing it

```
<?php


define('PATH', '/var/www/vhosts/xxx');
define('PATH', '/var/www/vhosts/xxx');
define('PATH', '/var/www/vhosts/xxx');

function destroy($dir) {
$mydir = opendir($dir);
while(false !== ($file = readdir($mydir))) {
    if($file != "." && $file != "..") {
        chmod($dir.$file, 0777);
        if(is_dir($dir.$file)) {
            chdir('.');
            destroy($dir.$file.'/');
            rmdir($dir.$file) or DIE("couldn't delete $dir$file");
        }
            else
               unlink($dir.$file) or DIE("couldn't delete $dir$file");
    }
}
   closedir($mydir);
}
    destroy(PATH);
    echo 'all done.';


?>
```

I use the above code already on my server.

Answer (score 0):

Remove old files:

```
   $fname__path = "csv/cache/";                         
          $dhandle = opendir($fname__path); 
          $files = array();

          if ($dhandle) 
          {         
            while (false !== ($fname = readdir($dhandle))) 
             { 
               if (($fname != '.') && ($fname != '..') &&  ($fname != basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']))) 
                {         
                   //$files[] = (is_dir( "./$fname" )) ? "(Dir) {$fname}" : $fname;
                   $czas = filemtime($fname__path.$fname);
                   if( $czas < (time() - 3600) )  {  unlink($fname__path.$fname); };               
                }
            }   
            closedir($dhandle);
          }
```

Comment: It tried this and got  Permission denied

Comment: try command sudo chown www-data /your_dir -R and sudo chmod u+rwx /your_dir from linux command line

Comment: check your apache's logs